# End of file for a WAV file is not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I went to https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ to see how to use pyaudio and found that the example for play has a problem:

```
while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
```

When run, this loop never exits and hangs in an endless loop. I changed the code to count down from `int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)` and add a few more cycles and see the following data when printed out:

```
c\x01\x9e\x01\x91\x01\xa5\x01\xaf\x01\xb8\x01\xb1\x01\xb8\x01'
i is:  5
data is:  b''
i is:  4
data is:  b''
i is:  3
data is:  b''
i is:  2
data is:  b''
i is:  1
data is:  b''
Start shutting down
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

So, when the wav file data is run through, there are empty spaces being passed but they don't register as alluded to by the sample code. I tried 'b\'\'', escaping the single quotes, but the program still loops endlessly and I get an `invalid syntax` error when I use the ` character.

Does anyone know why the code does NOT end execution when the EOF (null) is reached? The pyaudio page says to check here and I found nothing about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you an answer as to why this is happening but I ran into the same problem and was able to solve this by changing the while condition to work like the code sample on the ["documentation" part of the website](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/):

```py
while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
```